# In javascript it possible to convert the value of a string to an array?

Tags: javascript

I went searching for this and couldn't find a simple solution.
From a http request I extract a string eg. "myArray1", "myArray2", etc.
I have a number of arrays eg. myArray1, myArray2, etc. in my code and I'd like to access the elements of the array that corresponds to the string returned from the http request.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [split()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp).. or i just don't understand your question.

Comment: Is the result of your HTTP request formatted as JSON? Then you could do this: `myArray1 = JSON.parse(yourHttpResultString)`

Comment: Have these arrays to be properties of an object so you can access them by name.

Comment: you might need to elaborate with an example code

Comment: Please specify what you have as an input and your desired output

Answer (score -1):

If I understand correctly, you could store the arrays in an object and access them dynamically based on the response string:

```js
const arrays = {
  myArray1: ['foo'],
  myArray2: ['bar'],
};

const responseString = 'myArray1';

console.log(arrays[responseString]);
```